# Issue with setting up mongod local server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server

I tried setting up a local server for REST API endpoint with MongoDB using the command:

```
(base) surya@surya-Inspiron-7572:~/webdev/datastore/mongodb$ mongod --dbpath=data --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

But my server couldnt start up efficiently

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61G9r.png)

Can anyone please verify it

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Using relative path `--dbpath=data` does not look smart to me. Better use an absolute path. Ensure this path exist.

Comment: I even tried with full path.. Yet i got the same error 
surya@surya-Inspiron-7572:~/webdev/fullstack_webdev_course3/mongodb$ mongod --dbpath=home/surya/webdev/fullstack_webdev_course3/mongodb/data --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-25T09:58:19.813+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}

Answer (score 0):

The 'SocketException'... 'Address already in use` error print sounds like you might already have something running on the port 27017.

Try one of these commands to check:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
sudo ss -tulwn | grep LISTEN
sudo lsof -i:27017 ## see a specific port ##
sudo nmap -sTU -O IP-address-Here
```

Reference: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/

Comment: I think the "something" is an already running mongod process., Simply check with `ps -fe | grep mongo`.

Comment: This is the output i got from the command (base) surya@surya-Inspiron-7572:~$ ps -fe | grep mongo
mongodb     1204       1  0 09:50 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=/run/mongodb --config /etc/mongodb.conf
surya       4496    4477  0 09:58 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongo

Comment: Your MongoDB is already running, to try to start it twice. Most likely MongoDB is defined as a service (as it should be) and starts automatically when you start your machine.